# Front page render problems in FF with full page zoom

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The front pages (and only the front pages) of both gaming and meta.gaming give me a rendering issue in FF 3.6(.11) with full page zoom set to 150%. In my test, any full page zoom > 100% shows this problem.

Gaming:
[image]

Meta.gaming:
[image]

I found out it's a problem with the `#tabs` selector and the margins. When I change `margin: 2px 5px` to `margin: 1px 5px` it works as expected. I also realized that only the front pages show the tabs *active, features, ...* are move into the page from the border, on the other pages, see example, they're not.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have put in a fix for this. Should be in the next deployment